# Python-get function's return value when called using Concurrent.Futures module as ThreadPool

Tags: python, multithreading, return-value, concurrent.futures

I have created a ThreadPool using Concurrent.Futures module.
I have created threads and everything worked fine.

But now i have a function which i want to make it parallel with threads,
the problem is i need the return value of the function each thread should run and not sure how to get it when using the futures threadPool module.
is there a way?

Comment: I'm using submit to lunch the threads to the pool.

Comment: You just call the `result()` method on the `Future` instance returned by the `submit()` method on the executor instance.

Comment: From what i understood the Result method return the state of the thread. what i need is the return value from the function the thread run.

Comment: What is the state?  The `result()` method returns the _result_ from the function (or raises an exception if the function raised one).

Answer (score 6):

Your understanding of `result()` is absolutely wrong. From [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=concurrent.futures#concurrent.futures.Future.result):

> **result(timeout=None)**
>   **Return the value returned by the call. If the call hasn’t yet completed then this method will wait up to timeout
>   seconds.** If the call hasn’t completed in timeout seconds, then a
>   TimeoutError will be raised. timeout can be an int or float. If
>   timeout is not specified or None, there is no limit to the wait time.
>
> If the future is cancelled before completing then CancelledError will
>   be raised.

It is very clear that `result()` will give you the result of that function you submit.